# In Fighting Fantasy books, what is considered "one item"?

Tags: equipment, books

Step 313 in The Warlock of Firetop Mountain says, in part:

> He wears a suit of leather armor no better than your own, holds a wooden shield on one wrist and clutches a steel-bladed sword in his other hand. In his pockets are 8 Gold Pieces and around his neck is a silver crucifix.
>
> You may take any two of these items you wish.

Are the gold pieces collectively one item (i.e., I could take the gold pieces and something else)? Or if I take the crucifix, does that mean I can only take 1 gold piece? I would assume the latter, but then I don't see the point of being told he has 8 gold pieces if I could never take more than two anyways.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may be better suited in [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've closed this question as off-topic because CYOA, Fighting Fantasy, and other gamebook-style books [have been determined](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/544/321) ([twice](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5385)) to be outside our site's topic.

Comment: @daze413 rules about a game in SciFi.SE? I'm not really convinced they would accept it. Maybe Card and Board Games?

Comment: I'm not sure if we would accept this question over at B&CG.SE, but I think it is worth a shot

Comment: @Michael: Your answer is available on the SF&F site. :)

Comment: Rolled back the edit. A question about "RPGs in general" will be closed as too broad. And it's totally irrelevant to the problem you have which is about the gamebooks.